# R Reducer is not working properly in Amazon EMR

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce, emr

I have done a map reduce code in R to run in Amazon EMR.

My input file format:

`URL1 word1 word2 word3
URL2 word4 word2 word3
URL3 word1 word7 word2`

I'm expecting the output as: URLs are concat with spaces

`word1 URL1 URL3
word2 URL1 URL2 URL3
word3 URL1 URL2
.. ... ..`

But EMR is using 3 reducers and creating 3 output files. File wise the output is correct, it is combining values, no duplicate keys. But if we see the 3 files together, there are duplicate keys.

Output file 1:

`word1 URL1 URL3
word2 URL1
.. ..`

Output file 2:

`word2 URL2 URL3
word3 URL1
.. ..`

See, the `word2` is distributed to 2 files. I need one key is in only one file.

I'm using, Hadoop Streaming in EMR. Please suggest me the correct settings to remove the duplicate keys in different files.

I assume my mapper is working fine. This is my reducer:

```
process <- function(mat){

rows = nrow(mat)
cols = ncol(mat)

for(i in 1:rows)
{

    for(j in i+1:rows)
    {
        if(j<=rows)
        {
            if(toString(mat[i,1])==toString(mat[j,1]))
            {
            x<-paste(mat[i,2],mat[j,2],sep=" ")
            mat[i,2]=x
            mat<-mat[-j,]
            rows<-rows-1
            }
        }
    }
}

write.table(mat, file=stdout(), quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
}

reduce <- function(input){
  #create column names to make is easier to work with the data set
  names <- c("word", "value")
  cols = as.list(vector(length=2, mode="character"))
  names(cols) <- names

  #read from the input
  hsTableReader(file=input, cols, ignoreKey=TRUE, chunkSize=100000, FUN=process, sep=" ")


}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you're running?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a combiner to gather the same keys into the same reducer? This way you should be able to gather all words with a similar key into a single reducer. Check some *wordcount* examples with a combiner to understand how a combiner class works.